# DirectX: How to perfectly sync two outputs

Tags: directx, synchronization, multiple-monitors

I want to perfectly sync two screen outputs. I'm working with DirectX11, two screens output on a single video card adapter. Currently my basic algorithm is:

```
mainloop:
{
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
        render the scene for output i

    for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
        swapchain(i)->Present()
}
```

Everything is working. But some users report they "feel" both images on two screens are not perfectly in sync. ( I use exactly same screens, and everything is running on the same video adapter).

By doing two `swapchain->present` I'm not sure that both are in sync. My question:

Is there a way to be sure both outputs are in sync? For instance, is it possible to have one only swapchain for two outputs?

thanks in advance

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

There are few options you could try

***Option 1:*** Do the presentation immediately without waiting for the monitor sync.

```
d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
```

(this is not a best option but for some applications it doesn't matter)

***Option 2:*** If the adapter count is 2 then you could create **2 full screen** (not window mode) exclusive devices for rendering and presentation. Here you could sync the monitors on every frame presentation.

```
d3dpp.Windowed = FALSE; 
d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE;
```

***Device 1:***

```
g_pD3D->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, g_hWnd_0,
                         D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &g_pd3dDevice_0 );
```

***Device 2:***

```
 g_pD3D->CreateDevice( 1, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, g_hWnd_0,
                          D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &g_pd3dDevice_1 );
```

***Option 3:*** You could try **triple buffering** instead of double buffering.